# Replace Method in another Class

Tags: java

I'm would like to make a Minecraft plugin that replaces methods in other plugins with ones in the plugin, for easy customization of the plugins.

Is there any way to simply replace a method of one class with one of another? Kinda like using @override, however it overrides the original method as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an aspect-oriented framework like [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/), by advising around the method calls on the class you want to override, and invoking your new method.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I'm about intermediate level in Java, I'm still learning. :/

Comment: Hmmm, aspects might be a little much if your at intermediate level. I'll see if I can whip up a sample. In the meantime, maybe you can describe your issue in more detail, as there are possibly other solutions to it.

Comment: Basically I just want to put a piece of code in a method of another class/jar/plugin without directly modifying the plugin. I basically just want it to load the first plugin, then load the second plugin, and one of the methods in the second plugin "overlaps" a method on the first plugin. When the method from the first plugin is called, it instead uses the method from the second plugin. I tried to be as descriptive as possible, if I'm still not clear I can explain more. :p

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to modify a method to replace with your own.

You can use Java reflection though to replace a instance of something that you modify. But you can not modify the method directly without reflection..

What I mean by this. Is to extend one of the classes your overriding and than replace the original instance in the files that hold it.

**Be Careful when doing so**

Here is a good tutorial for reflection [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

You can also further [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+reflection) it.

Do note. This kind of replacement is a bit hackish. It is not encouraged to do such on bukkit. Especially on ***bukkit*** code.